# WCF returning "The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match"

Tags: wcf

The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were..."

Any idea and Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

In my case my web.config was not well formed, then when the service is consumed an error occurs the cuel returns it to me as an html.
As I realized. Why try to open the web config by IIS con alone and inform me I left the error that the xml was not well formed